# How to integrate AVCam into iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, avcam

I'm trying to use Apple's AVCam project for my app. But I'm quite confused how to do this. I want to open the camera of AVCam when pressing a button. When I add files of AVCam to my project, there is an error: Apple Mach-O Linker error, checking in build phases, there are errors for two storyboards of AVCam. Since AVCam use storyboard so I don't know how to include it into another app. Please help me find a way to do it, thanks.

P/S: I use .xib instead of storyboard for my own app.

Comment: Try making sure the device has a camera before opening the camera. Yes, this is ridiculous, but iOS Simulator DOESN'T have a camera, and can't emulate an iPhone camera.

Comment: Yeah I knew that but AVCam can be still opened, it is an error just when we try to record or take still image. But now my app with integrated AVCam is not even built successfully

Comment: If you're running it in the simulator, then there will be an error. The camera can't take a picture when there is no camera. However, on a physical iOS device, then AVCam should work fine.